# Spark 3.0 scala.None$ is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

While using elasticsearch-hadoop library for reading elasticsearch index with empty attribute, getting the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.None$ is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

There is open defect in github for the same with steps to reproduce it: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1635

> Spark: 3.1.1
> Elasticsearch-Hadoop : elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-7.12.0
> Elasticsearch : 2.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked by setting elasticsearch-hadoop property **es.field.read.empty.as.null = no**

```
.option("es.field.read.empty.as.null", "no")
```

From Elasticsearch [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_advanced_settings):
**es.field.read.empty.as.null (default yes)**
Whether elasticsearch-hadoop will treat empty fields as null.